# Converting an array to an object of nested objects for a tree diagram in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

i'm attempting to create a Tree Diagram with react-d3-js. It needs to be in a specific format. So i need to convert the initial data that i have to the format.

This is a diagram for a shop to see the distribution chain and who is allowed to make a purchase from specific nodes.

Initial Data:

```
store.name = 'Absolut Chocolat' //Main Parent


store.shopconditions: [
    {
        "role": "agent",
        "condition": ["owner", "stokist"]
    }, 
    {
        "role": "stokist",
        "condition": ["owner", "master stokist"]
    },
    {
        "role": "master stokist",
        "condition": ["owner"]
    }
    ]

// If role is agent, then they are allowed to buy from 'owner' and 'stokist'
```

Here's the hardcoded ideal output:

```
  orgChart = {
    name: 'Absolut Chocolat',
    children: [
      { name: 'Agent' },
      {
        name: 'Stokist',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Agent',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'Master Stokist',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Stokist',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'Agent',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
```

With a few for each loops, i've gotten to the first 2 layers of the intended output but i cannot find a way to get more than that.

Here is what i got so far:
[Agent node is not under Master Stokist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bny5Y.png)

Current code:

```
  let chartData = { name: store.name, children: [] };

  store.shopconditions.forEach((i) => {
    i.condition.forEach((c) => {
      if (c === 'owner') {
        chartData.children.push({ name: i.role });
      }
    });
  });

  const chartDataParser = (data) => {

    data.children.map((i) => {
      for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(i)) {
        store.shopconditions.forEach((c) => {
          c.condition.forEach((o) => {
            if (o === v) {
              if (!i.children) {
                i.children = [{ name: c.role }];
              } else {
                i.children.push({ name: c.role });
              }
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  };

  chartDataParser(chartData);
```

Current output:

```
{
    name: 'Absolut Chocolat',
    children: [
      { name: 'Agent' },
      {
        name: 'Stokist',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Agent',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'Master Stokist',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Stokist',
            // Missing children: Agent Node
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
```

What the tree diagram should look like:
[As you can see under Master Stokist node, Agent is under Stokist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RoyR.png)

The Agent node is not reached under the stokist node in the right most chain. I need a fix to my current code so it can go to that extra layer. Thanks in advance. Looking forward to learn from your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an object that lists children by role and then use that to recursively build the nodes of the object. Possibly something like the following:

```js
const store = {
  name: 'Absolut Chocolat',
  shopconditions: [
    { "role": "agent", "condition": ["owner", "stokist"], name: 'Agent' }, 
    { "role": "stokist", "condition": ["owner", "master stokist"], name: 'Stockist' },
    { "role": "master stokist", "condition": ["owner"], name: 'Master Stockist' },
  ]
};

const build_role_map = (store) => {
  let role_map = Object.fromEntries(
    store.shopconditions.map((v) => [v.role, { ...v, children: [] }])
  );
  role_map.owner = { "role": "owner", "condition": [], children: [], name: store.name };

  store.shopconditions.forEach(
    ({ role, condition }) => {
      condition.forEach((parent) => { role_map[parent].children.push(role) })
    }
  );
  
  return role_map;
};

const build_node = (role_map, { name, children }) => {
  let node = { name };
  
  if(children.length > 0)
    node.children = children.map((child) => build_node(role_map, role_map[child]));
  
  return node;
};

const build_tree = (store) => {
  const role_map = build_role_map(store);
  
  return build_node(role_map, role_map.owner);
};

console.log(build_tree(store));
```